How to jump to specific filtered logs in K9s
In K9s, how does one navigate efficiently to the log lines surrounding a specific filtered event?
Desired behaviour:

In container logs, Use / to filter for a specific event.
Select the event
Jump to the line showing surrounding code.

Is the above workflow possible in K9s, and if yes, how?
Example:
I searched for all lines containing error, and want to jump straight to the surrounding context of one result.

Currently I achieve this by copying the exact timestamp, and filtering for the surrounding time period. This feel rather tedious.
I reckon I am missing something obvious, but none of the shortcuts I tried appear to have the desired functionality.
I have already read this discussion, which does not cover my question.
